# deserialize JSON data for different types of objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Im using GSON on an Android device.

I have JSON data coming in, but it can come in the form of a few different objects.

This is how I think I need to handle it.

```
public class Command 
{
    public String Command;  
}


String json = {"Command":"Something", "date":"now"}

String command = gson.fromJson(message, Command.class);
```

Then switch on command

```
Switch(command)
{

case: something
//deserialize to "something" object;
break;

case: other somthing
//deserialize to "other somthing" object;
break;

case: object 3
//deserialize to "object 3" object;
break;

}
```

Does GSON have some sort of Auto Mapping to the best suited object, so i dont have to make a custom object handler and deseraialize the String twice?

Comment: So you have multiple json schema coming from the same source?  And you are trying to cast them to the appropriate beans?

Comment: yes, exactly. Is there a way to do this easily? Maybe a example or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse it as a general JsonObject using

```
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

then find something unique about each json schema and then depending on which schema convert it to a bean using

```
    gson.fromJson(jsonObject, AppropriateBean.class);
```

Comment: Im going to go with this approach, although its not as sophisticated as I was hoping.

Comment: does this potentially fail when dealing with objects that have non primitive data types that need to be deserialized?

Answer (score 0):

I think an [example](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) of what you are trying to achieve is covered in the user guide. See the part about [Serializing and Deserializing Collection with Objects of Arbitrary Types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types). They recommend to use the underlying parser API and then the `fromGson` method onward, so you don't have to parse intermediary objects, which sounds like a good approach to me. But the also provide two alternatives that you might try.